# How can I place WooCommerce Breadcumbs onto my homepage?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

I have placed `<?php woocommerce_breadcrumb(); ?>` into my header.php file.  This allows me to call the breadcrumbs in every page apart from the homepage.

Does anyone know what alterations I may need to do, in order for said breadcrumbs to appear on the homepage as well as the other pages across the website?

Comment: may be you can consider using hook to add it try wp_head hook .

Comment: Thanks for your direction.  I have tried various Hooks and whilst they appear on Product pages, the breadcrumbs do not appear on the homepage still, despite the Hook revealing that I have correctly hooked `woocommerce_breadcrumb();` Could it be that the breadcrumbs simply do not recognise the home page and so does not become visible?  If so, is there a work around for this?

Comment: Have you gone through the doc https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce_breadcrumb/ here last parameter specifies either you will include fronpage in your bread crumb specify that and try again .